How can I create DatabricksSubmitRunOperator tasks dynamically in Airflow?
I have following use case:
I am trying to create an Airflow DAG which will be used to automate historical data load. I am passing 5 arguments to this DAG - jar_path, main_class_name, start_param, end_param, max_run_range.
Based on start_param, end_param and max_run_range, a list of dates is created. For each individual date of this list, I want to trigger a DatabricksSubmitRunOperator task.
I have below code but when I execute it, I am getting this error for the dynamic tasks that it creates -
Airflow DAG code:
@dag(default_args=runParams,
     schedule_interval=None,
     start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 4, 22, tz="US/Pacific"),
     tags=["historical_load"]
     )
def CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST():

    @task
    def get_args():
        context = get_current_context()
        jar_path = context['dag_run'].conf['jar_path']
        main_class_name = context['dag_run'].conf['main_class_name']
        start_param = context['dag_run'].conf['start_param']
        end_param = context['dag_run'].conf['end_param']
        max_run_range = context['dag_run'].conf['max_run_range']

        return {
            'jar_path': jar_path,
            'main_class_name': main_class_name,
            'start_param': start_param,
            'end_param': end_param,
            'max_run_range': max_run_range
        }

    @task
    def process_args(args) -> list[dict]:
        start_date = args['start_param']
        end_date = args['end_param']
        interval = args['max_run_range']

        date_params = []
        idx = 0
        while start_date <= end_date:
            dict_item = {idx: start_date}
            date_params.append(dict_item)
            idx += 1
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() + timedelta(days=interval)
            start_date = str(start_date)

        args['date_params_dict'] = date_params

        return date_params

    @task
    def spark_task(args, dt_dict):
        dt = ""
        for key, val in dt_dict.items():
            dt = val
        DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
            task_id=f"process_task_{dt}",
            new_cluster=jobCluster,
            dag=dag,
            databricks_conn_id="${DBxConnID}",
            access_control_list=accessControlList,
            spark_jar_task={"main_class_name": args['main_class_name'], "parameters": dt},
            libraries=[{"jar": args['jar_path']}],
        )

    spark_task.partial(args=get_args()).expand(dt_dict=process_args(get_args()))

CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST_DAG = CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST()

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 188, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 193, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/can/CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST.py", line 122, in spark_task
    DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 376, in apply_defaults
    task_group = TaskGroupContext.get_current_task_group(dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/utils/task_group.py", line 489, in get_current_task_group
    return dag.task_group
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'task_group'

Even though I am not using TaskGroup, I am not sure why is it giving this error.
Env used: Azure Databricks, Astronomer for Airflow(airflow version 2.4.3), jar is created on spark/scala code.
I have also tried passing the dates list directly into .expand() method but it also resulted in the same error. 
For a sample argument of 3 dates (start_param='2024-03-01',end_param='2024-03-03',max_run_range=1),  the code is able to create 3 mapped instances but it fails in each instance with the above error.
(Ignore start and end tasks)
For other variations that I tried, the code failed without even creating dynamic tasks.

I was able to get a successful run with some changes. Posting the working code for other's reference.
@dag(default_args=runParams,
     schedule_interval=None,
     start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 4, 22, tz="US/Pacific"),
     tags=["CAN", "data_layer", "com-can", "historical_load"]
     )
def CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST():

    @task
    def get_args():
        context = get_current_context()
        jar_path = context['dag_run'].conf['jar_path']
        main_class_name = context['dag_run'].conf['main_class_name']
        start_param = context['dag_run'].conf['start_param']
        end_param = context['dag_run'].conf['end_param']
        max_run_range = context['dag_run'].conf['max_run_range']

        return {
            'jar_path': jar_path,
            'main_class_name': main_class_name,
            'start_param': start_param,
            'end_param': end_param,
            'max_run_range': max_run_range
        }

    @task
    def process_args(args) -> list:
        start_date = args['start_param']
        end_date = args['end_param']
        interval = args['max_run_range']
        class_name = args['main_class_name']

        date_params = []
        while start_date <= end_date:
            list_item = {
                "main_class_name": class_name,
                "parameters": [start_date]
            }
            date_params.append(list_item)
            start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() + timedelta(days=interval)
            start_date = str(start_date)

        return date_params

    args = get_args()
    date_params = process_args(args)

    spark_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator.partial(
        task_id=f"process_task",
        new_cluster=jobCluster,
        databricks_conn_id="allyuen",
        access_control_list=accessControlList,
        libraries=[{"jar": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_args')['jar_path'] }}"}],
    ).expand(spark_jar_task=date_params)

CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST_DAG = CAN_HIST_LOAD_TEST()

